# Is there any way to speed up actions in XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

There are some actions in XCOM 2 that I would like to see sped up.  There is sometimes waiting times that seem unnecessary. Are there any settings or anything available to speed up actions?

Comment: +1, I was just wondering about this this morning. It's worth noting that you can usually tab to another soldier while the first one is completing their animation. This actually skips the evac animation.

Comment: One simple thing that might not be obvious to new players is that when you are moving out of combat, you can move one of your soldiers while the previous one is still doing their movement animation. In most other turn-based combat games, you have to wait for the previous turn to be completed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The mod "**[Stop Wasting My Time](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=620600092)**" (made by someone who is also active here, btw) would be just what you need. It removes unnecessary waiting times in the game, speeding your turns (and probably even the enemies turns) up significantly. Note however, that not all pauses in the game could be eliminated, as some of them are hardcoded into the game.

I use the mod myself, and I am totally happy with it.

Beware, though: as with all mods, deactivating the mod (should you decide you dont like it) prevents you from *loading a save* made with that mod. There is an experimental mod to "fix" this, but I would still recommend to *Backup* your saved game before installing any mod!

Comment: +1 for far better detail than my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: :D​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I wonder how this would invalidate previous saves. How would this effect a save enough that it's no longer compatible? Unless they hard-coded in a check to prevent unforeseen issues.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Every mod has that effect, because it would be a difficult task to determine automatically whether a mod was actually backwards compatible or not. It's much simpler to just say "if your save contained this mod, you need that mod to open the save again".

Comment: If you play Skyrim, you will realize what a huge issue this is.  You can break things that are MUCH further into the game, and at that point it is pure rage-quit material because you can't fix it.

Answer (score 46):

In addition to [Stop Wasting My Time](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=620600092) *(made by a very mysterious and handsome author)* already mentioned, there are a few other time-saving mods I highly recommend:

- [Instant Avenger Menu](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=628187112): Instantly move between rooms in the Avenger.  Also speeds up Avatar Project updates.
- [Evac all](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618669868): Adds a button to evac all units at once, rather than having to do it one-by-one
- [Overwatch all](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=621695447): Same, but for Overwatch.
- [Strip Primary Weapons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618504171): Adds a button to remove all weapons from all non-mission soldiers before a mission.
- If you like to color-code your soldiers by class, [Automatically Color Units](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=622023580) or [Character Pool Uniforms](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=619905919) will save you time.
- [No Startup Movies](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618203782): Skips the movies at the start of the game, speeding up the initial load time.
- [Always Show Shot Breakdowns](https://www.nexusmods.com/xcom2/mods/121): Saves you from having to click the left-arrow on the attack screen all the time *(which is actually a bug)*

Also, the "experimental mod" mentioned by the other answer, [Ignore Missing Content Warning](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=619141883), allows you to force-load a save game created with mods that are no longer installed.  You wouldn't want to do this with any mods that add actual content *(new flags/models/weapons/classes etc.)*, but all of the mods listed here *should* be togglable at will.

Answer (score 9):

Not in-game actions, exactly, but there's [currently an undocumented feature](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2016/02/16/why-does-caps-lock-make-xcom-2-load-faster/) that lets you skip loading times after missions (i.e., the ones where everyone is sitting on the dropship heading back to base) *just by pressing Caps Lock*.

> "Hitting the key, through a Rube-Goldberg-esque series of events, forces all outstanding load requests to be filled immediately in a single frame. This causes a massive hitch, and potentially could crash the game. If you don’t care about those adverse effects the synchronous load is faster." (developer at Firaxis)

I tried it last night, and it did shorten the loading to a couple of seconds. Just be aware that, as Firaxis says, this could possibly crash your game, so make sure you have autosaves turned on if you do this.

Incidentally, I found out about this while searching for information on the Lock and Load continent bonus, which I hope becomes the official name of the feature.

Comment: +1 for interpreting "actions" loosely and for explaining what actually happens to accelerate the load.

Answer (score 4):

There is now an official solution to this as [part of the latest Xcom2 patch](https://xcom.com/news/en-xcom-2-patch-now-live) without needing to use any mods:

> Players can also opt into the new “Zip Mode” option by pausing the
>   game at any time and activating it under gameplay options. Zip Mode
>   will create a faster paced experience that speeds up animations and
>   some delays in gameplay.

Another tip is you can press "tab" while moving a soldier, to switch to another solider during the action. This means you can quickly have 3-4 people moving "simultaneously" across your map. However if you try to press tab, and it doesnt work during a specific soliders action, it is because that soldier is about to trigger "something" (i.e. a pod, a voice script, a civilian running - *anything*).

Answer (score 2):

For faster movement, edit:

```
XCOM 2\XCom2-WarOfTheChosen\XComGame\Config\DefaultAnimation:
```

```
 - MaxUnitRunRate=1.75;
```

---

To speed up slow motion reaction, change:

```
XCOM 2\XCom2-WarOfTheChosen\XComGame\Config\DefaultCamera:
```

```
 - ReactionFireWorldSloMoRate=0.7 ;
```

---

To fly faster Skyranger, change values:

```
XCOM 2\XCom2-WarOfTheChosen\XComGame\Config\DefaultGameData:
```

```
 - Acceleration=(X=0.15, Y=0.15, Z=80.0)
 - MaxSpeedFlying=0.2
 - MaxSpeedVertical=70.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In XCOM2's launch options add the *-allowconsole* command line argument.
Next, open the file *XCOM 2\XCom2-WarOfTheChosen\XComGame\Config\DefaultInput* and change:

---

`.Bindings=(Name="RightMouseButton", Command="Right_Mouse_Button_Press | onrelease Right_Mouse_Button_Release", bPrimaryBinding=True)`

to:

`.Bindings=(Name="RightMouseButton", Command="Right_Mouse_Button_Press | Slomo 1.2 | onrelease Right_Mouse_Button_Release", bPrimaryBinding=True)`

(Note the addition of `Slomo` and its value!)

---

(Adjust 1.2 to your preferred speed: increasing the number will increase the speed.)

Comment: How does changing the right mouse button input speed increase action speed? Also, "slomo" suggests slowing the input speed down: does increasing its value increase or decrease speed?

Comment: Slomo command will fast forward or slow down the game. A multiplier of 2 would make everything in the game be twice as fast, a multiplier of 0.5 would make the game run in slowmotion.  Adding this command to the right mouse button activates it when the movement is made.

Comment: Ah,  it's a bind! Thanks for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 0):

[CheatEngine](http://www.cheatengine.org/)'s Speedhack feature works pretty well in XCOM, I usually have it on at 2x speed. (I've tried Stop Wasting My Time, but the effects seem pretty minor.) It basically has the effect of running the game loop at the chosen modifier, so all animations run twice as fast.

Sounds aren't affected, which is mainly a problem in cutscenes, which will get massively desynchronized. CheatEngine has hotkey support, so it should be possible to set up a toggle to disable the speedhack in cutscenes.